# Mod rewrite test.php?p=one to test/one

Tags: forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I rewrite rules like `site.com/product/p1` to `site.com/product.php?p=p1` successfully.

Now, I want to the the opposite, convert the query that is received from a form submission `site.com/product.php?id=1234&name=test` to `site.com/product/test/1234` i.e. I don't want the site visitor to see the query parameters.

To make things more clear: on my site I have a form with two text input fields (and a few hidden fields as well); visitors can enter the product id and product name and submit the form. I want the resulting url (after the form submission) to be flat (`site.com/product/test/1234`) and not include any params.

Of course, I want my script (`product.php`) to retrieve all the parameters from the form. I guess I could do that in the same fashion that I turn `site.com/product/p1` into `site.com/product.php?p=p1`.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite over doing a redirect in your PHP script? The end result is the same URL, and the script has more flexibility to deal with query parameters coming in different orders.

Comment: Ah, you suggest that my script could 1) retrieve all the params and then 2) redirect to whatever url? That sounds great! Could that be achieved through mod rewrite as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` will not be flexible enough to do this in general. It's fine when you have one (and only one) query parameter to handle. As you add more, you need to handle every possible combination of query parameters, and have a new rule for each. `mod_rewrite` is only appropriate if you can no longer serve URLs in the old style, for example if you are upgrading a third-party server you cannot modify, and want to have `httpd` handle redirecting old bookmarked links to the new locations.

It is best to handle this inside your PHP script itself. The script at the "old" `product.php?id=1234&name=test` URL should read the `GET` parameters and return a `HTTP 301` response ("Moved Permanently") to the new `product/test/1234` URL. This will work if the request goes to `product.php`, or `product.php?name=test`, or `product.php?id=1234`, or `product.php?name=test&id=1234`. The script determines what to do with missing values, and how to build the replacement URL.

To do the rewrite with just a single query parameter, it will look like the reverse of your successful rewrite rule, e.g.

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING}    ^p=(.*)$
RewriteRule     /product.php       /product/%1   [R]
```

Comment: Sounds legit. Could you help me out and write what should the mod rewrite settings be in case I'm dealing with one parameter only?

Comment: Updated with an example for a single query parameter.